# Convert Data URI to Blob

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, data-uri, identicon

I'm currently using [Jdenticon](https://jdenticon.com) library for generating user `identicons` as a default profile picture. I'd like to convert the data URI for `SVG` to a [Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) or make it as an image file so that I could store an image file into [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

I've tried a few example code from Stack Overflow, but none of them were worked for me. *(I've not converted the data into base64. I don't think SVG syntax has any crazy characters in it.)*

```
createIdenticonBlob(hash: string) {
  if (hash) {
    let svg = jdenticon.toSvg(hash, Math.min(50, 50));
    let uri = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svg);
    return this.uploadService.convertDataURIToBlob(uri); // I'm not sure :(
  }
}
```

> [jdenticon.toSvg(hash|value, size[, padding])](https://jdenticon.com/js-api.html#tosvg)

I'm not sure how to convert `Data URI` to an image file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `svg` encoded in base64?

Comment: As I said, I've not converted SVG into base64. Should I?

Comment: No, it's just that the example in your link is encoded to b64. So if you confirm it's not, all you need is `new Blob([svg], {type:"image/svg+xml"})`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kaiido. I've made a very simple mistake. I'll accept your answer if you leave it as an answer. One more thing btw, I'd like to store an image in a JPEG format. Any ideas?

Comment: That'a a completely different question that has already been answered many times. Look to "svg to raster javascript" or  "svg to png javascript". ( you dont want jpeg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to convert a dataURI to a file, you want to make a file from the svg markup, which is just text, and if your plugin really returns an svg markup, this is really easy to do:

```
createIdenticonBlob(hash: string) {
  if (hash) {
    let svg = jdenticon.toSvg(hash, Math.min(50, 50));
    let blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
    return blob;
  }
}
```

Comment: My code look exactly the same as your answer.  I'll take a look at `SVG to PNG`. Thank you once again.